# Tweepy: Tweeperror in a loop using cursor

Tags: python, loops, cursor, tweepy

I am actually trying to retrieve the friends of a certain Twitter User using the Cursor method. Because I wanna be fast I want to retrieve 5000 at a time. However sometimes the iterator gives a Tweep error because one of this 5000 user (at least) is protected. Is there a way to go over it? Without loosing information but the id of the one causing problems?

```py
def getPageFollowers(company):
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, id = company).pages():
        yield page
```

And I call it here:

```
id_followers[my_list[i]] += next(followerFollowerIterator)
```

I then get the following error:
TweepError: Not authorized.

Can somoene help me please? :)

Comment: Maybe you can try to catch the exception and pass? will it do the trick for you?

Comment: But if I catch the exception I will use the whole page right, because since it retrieves 5000 at a time, I cannot only catch the one that annoys me?

Comment: did you figure out a way around this?